# What would be the way to model the upper part of the bench?

Tags: modeling

I am new to blender and I wanted to model this bench. What would be the easiest and most accurate way to model the top of this bench (I'm talking about those little folds and deepenings). Thank you in advance and sorry for such basic question[image]

[image]

Comment: That's really helpful, but how do I actually make this unit mesh in step 1? (I'll add a picture of it to my post)

Comment: Hi :). Scroll through the answer, there's a specific gif about it ;)

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't see that. Anyway thanks for a quick response.